# How to build LIBSVM on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, makefile, visual-studio-2017, libsvm

I'm trying to use LIBSVM with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. I installed the libsvm-3.22 Under /windows directory there is a Dll file and a bunch of exe files but no lib file. Following the instructions in the Readme file I tried to build by running in cmd window:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat

```
nmake -f C:\...\libsvm-3.22\Makefile.win clean all
```

The result is the error message

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'svm.h'

If I run this command instead to build the lib file

```
nmake -f C:\...\libsvm-3.22\Makefile.win lib
```

it gives a similar error

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'svm.cpp'

Could any one help please?

Comment: You can create a .lib from your .dll - https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/

Comment: WOW! thanks a lot, that actually worked and I can now successfully build my code!

Answer (score 2):

[Create .lib file from .dll](https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/) (duplicated here just in case original page disappears)
Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt, you find its shortcut in Start->Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio->Tools. Now run the `dumpbin` command to get a list of all exported functions of your dll:

```
dumpbin /exports C:\yourpath\yourlib.dll>yourlib.def
```

This will create a textfile yourlib.def:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

1    0 00017770 jcopy_block_row
2    1 00017710 jcopy_sample_rows
3    2 000176C0 jdiv_round_up
4    3 000156D0 jinit_1pass_quantizer
5    4 00016D90 jinit_2pass_quantizer
6    5 00005750 jinit_c_coef_controller
...etc
```

Now open yourlib.def and remove all but the function names and and put the line “EXPORTS” at its top. My yourlib.def file looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
jcopy_block_row
jcopy_sample_rows
jdiv_round_up
jinit_1pass_quantizer
jinit_2pass_quantizer
jinit_c_coef_controller
...
```

Now from that definition file, we can finally create the .lib file. We use the `lib` tool for this, so run this command in your Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
lib /def:C:\mypath\mylib.def /OUT:C:\mypath\mylib.lib
```